# Unexpected character (v) at position 4. Json Parsing Error

Tags: java, json

My .json file is that:

```
{
"Name": "Jack",
"Surname": "London",
"Price": "167"}
```

And error is,

```
Unexpected character (v) at position 4.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
    at main.main(main.java:80)
```

I am new at Json with Java. I searched other posts with releated with this situation but i haven't figure out my error. Thanks.

Comment: Since there's no `v` in that file, I suspect that you're not running it on that JSON.

Comment: The above example runs fine with `JSONParser`. Could you post all the content of the `json` file?

Comment: May be there are some weird, invisible character in your json. (for example: full-space character)